# While Loop increment issue

Tags: python, while-loop

Right now I am trying to make a simple program to separate the javascript links of a website but I'm running into issues with a while loop.

Here would be an example of an input:

```
001_usa_wool.jpg
002_china_silk.jpg
003_canada_cotton.jpg
004_france_wool.jpg
done
```

A simplified version of my code with just 3 parts is the following:

```
def ParseData(input):
    data = input.split('_')

    d = {}
    d['sku'] = data[0]
    d['country'] = data[1].capitalize()
    d['material'] = data[2].capitalize()
    return d

def Sku():
    myData = ParseData(input)
    sku = myData['sku']
    return sku

def Country():
    myData = ParseData(input)
    country = myData['country']
    return country

def Material():
    myData = ParseData(input)
    material = myData['material']
    return material

def Output():
    print (Sku()+'\t'+
           Country()+'\t'+
           Material()+'\t'+
           '\n')
```

Now here is how I tried to read it line by line:

```
def CleanInput(input):
    clean = input.split('.jpg')
    count = 0
    while (clean[count] != 'done'):
        ParseData(clean[count])
        Output()
        count = count+1

input = input('Enter your data: ')
CleanInput(input)
```

I believe I am not implementing the while loop correcting since my output is similar to:

```
001   Usa   Wool
001   Usa   Wool
001   Usa   Wool
```

Comment: try iterating on the items in clean: `for elem in clean:` ...

Comment: How are you giving the input to the program? Are you giving complete input you stated in the start of the question as whole to the `input()` function?

Comment: Yes, I am pasting `001_usa_wool.jpg002_china_silk.jpg003_canada_cotton.jpg004_france_wool.jpgdone` as the entire input

Comment: Your code has some masking (e.g. `input`) and severe repetition problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not exactly in your `while` loop , but in your functions - `Output()` , `Sku()` , `Material()` and `Country()` .

In the function `Output()` , you are printing the values by directly calling `Sku()`, etc.

In each of the function, I will take one as example - `Sku()` , you are calling `parseData` on `input` (Though this is a very bad naming, please use a better name, with this name you are overwriting the built-in `input` function, and later on you cannot call `input()` to take inputs from user)

The `input` always contains the entire string you inputted , and hence it contains all the `.jpg` names, when `parseData` goes through it, it always only picks up the first one.

Instead of using `input` in each function, we should make the functions parameterized and send in the value that needs to be printed as a parameter, as you are doing for `parseData` . And Example code -

```
def Sku(toprint):
    myData = ParseData(toprint)
    sku = myData['sku']
    return sku
.
.
.
def Output(toprint):
    print (Sku(toprint)+'\t'+
           Country(toprint)+'\t'+
           Material(toprint)+'\t'+
           '\n')
```

And in the while loop send in the current value to print as parameter to `Output()` -

```
def CleanInput(input):
    clean = input.split('.jpg')
    count = 0
    while (clean[count] != 'done'):
        ParseData(clean[count])
        Output(clean[count])
        count = count+1
```

Also , please do not use `input` as the name of the variable , it can cause issues , as i previously stated , as you are overwriting the built-in `input` function with that.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would make it more pythonic:

```
def CleanInput(input):
    clean = input.split('.jpg')
    for count, elem in enumerate(clean):
        if elem == 'done':
            break
        ParseData(elem)
        Output()
    return count

input_data = input('Enter your data: ')
how_many = CleanInput(input_data)
```

Assuming you really need `count`. By the way: you aren't using the return value of `ParseData`

Answer (score 0):

You have too many functions that call each other and take on vague requirements. It's hard to see what returns something, what prints, and so on. For example, your `CleanInput` calls `ParseData` and `Output`, but `Output` calls `Sku`, `Country`, and `Material`, each of which also calls `ParseData`. Oh, and capitalized variables should be reserved for classes - use `snake_case` for functions.

```
>>> s = "001_usa_wool.jpg002_china_silk.jpg003_canada_cotton.jpg004_france_wool.jpgdone"
>>> print(*("{}\t{}\t{}".format(*map(str.capitalize, item.split('_')))
... for item in s.split('.jpg') if item != 'done'), sep='\n')
001     Usa     Wool
002     China   Silk
003     Canada  Cotton
004     France  Wool
```